# How to edit URL with Fiddler(script)?

Tags: c#, fiddler

I want to edit a URL using fiddler. Doesn't have to be with fiddler script, but heres an approximation of how I'm doing it currently:

```
if (oSession.url.contains("example.com") {
  String oldUrl = oSession.url.ToString();
  Regex rgx = new Regex("1.2");
  String newUrl = rgx.Replace(oldUrl, "1.0");
}
```

This code is giving me a compiler error on the regex instantiation line: "The list of attributes does not apply to the current context". I'm not entirely sure what this means.

I'm also unsure how exactly to change the url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just got it:

```
oSession.url = oSession.url.Replace("1.2","1.0");
```

Comment: nice one, perfect. I found it handy to change the color to show which requests were redirected too - oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "Yellow";

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
    oSession.PathAndQuery = oSession.PathAndQuery.replace('/test1/', '/changed1/');
```